# Mouse activity not working in Html5ApplicationViewer on QT Webkit

Tags: html, qt, qt-creator

Using the QtCreator Application Wizard, I created a project using the Html5 application template.

It is supposed to show an `index.html` page.  The page works fine if I load it in Chrome.  My Qt program will render it correctly, but clicks don't work on buttons or links or scroll bars.

My code is exactly what the wizard generated:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Html5ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setOrientation(Html5ApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);

    viewer.showExpanded(); //Load the HTML Page
    viewer.loadFile(QLatin1String("html/index.html"));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Has anybody faced this problem?  I have Qt 4.7.2.

Comment: As asked, your question is not in a form that is answerable.  What is a "click"?  Is it a click on a link you expect to work out-of-the box to load a new page, or do you have special handlers to try and get hooks that run specialized Qt C++ code for arbitrary locations on your page?  Do you mean to imply that if the page is HTML4 then clicks work fine?  Etc. etc.  But welcome to StackOverflow, and please notice that there is an "edit" button so you can improve your question so it is actually answerable!  The site I usually suggest looking at is down right now, but useful: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Archived copy of the link so you can read it right now: [sscce.org at Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20090224023444/http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Those clicks are either some buttons or Links or scroll bars on HTML5 Page.Same HTML5 and JAVA Script works fine with Chrome am not sure if any settings has to be done in Qt Webkit or Qt version Problem.

Comment: Without code or knowing where your're working from it's not really possible to help you.  Are you starting from an example that comes with Qt such as the ["fancy browser"](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/webkit-fancybrowser.html)  Or something else?  Is this your own code or something you found?  *Please read the link I provided on what it takes to ask a good question, and edit your question to be more...good.*

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Html5ApplicationViewer viewer;

    viewer.setOrientation(Html5ApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer.showExpanded();

    //Load the HTML Page
    viewer.loadFile(QLatin1String("html/index.html"));
    return app.exec();
} The page index.html gets rendered.But any clicks on the page are not responding.

Comment: I've edited your question to show you two things. The first is how much information you left out which is required for anyone to know what you're talking about (not everyone who uses Qt has made an "Html5 application" in the wizard; I hadn't, and a Google for `Html5ApplicationViewer` shows few others have either.) Second point is that you can--and *should*--edit your questions to improve them. Are you using the default generated `index.html` or one of your own? Clarify your question on that point by [clicking here to edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12947996/edit)

Comment: The page loaded is not the default index.html, its my own HTML page.

Answer (score 4):

```
// don't know exactly what is the problem but you can try this    
viewer.webView()->setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution but I know what is the problem, the problem is the wizard dont put the right path to the index.html, so I did pull the index at /data/local/tmp/ just to test the app

viewer.loadFile(QLatin1String("/data/local/tmp/index.html"));

Answer (score 0):

well finaly this is the solution and its done!!!

viewer.loadUrl(QUrl("assets:/html/index.html"));